# Make a PNG image with "Hello World!" with programming APIs, in the shortest code possible

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, hello-world

So, I want you to make a PNG image that says "Hello world!" and nothing else on a distinguishable background using only an image making API (eg ImageMagick) and return the image. Fewest characters win, as usual. Oh, and you can use any color text.

Comment: Does it have to output `Hello World` or `Hello World!`?

Comment: @ryan Hello World! is the right one.

Comment: A lot of answers could save one character by replacing the double 'l' in 'hello' with the medieval Welsh ligatures 'Ỻ' or 'ỻ': once the chars have been transformed to pixels it shouldn't matter what their origin was as long as people still perceive 'heỻo world!' as 'hello world!'.

Comment: @timxyz Clearly not if you want the result to appear correctly on my browser!

Comment: @poldie Your browser changes PNG based on how the pixels got in there?

Comment: @timxyz: Arguably the extra stroke in `ỻ` violates the "nothing else" requirement.

Comment: @timxyz For me, ỻ is rendered as a box containing 1EFB. I tried to use it in my program anyway, and the result was a square. So, this is probably not very portable.

Comment: @timxyz No, it changes the characters you want changed into a PNG.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Sage notebook, 22

```
text("Hello world",0j)
```

Comment: Does this produce a PNG image?

Comment: Yup.  That's why I specified 'notebook', the CLI pops a window open, but the notebook saves a .png for the browser to display.

Answer (score 58):

## Bash + ImageMagick: <s>35</s> 33

Default font, default text size, default colours:

```
convert label:Hello\ world! a.png
```

and here's the result:

[image: Hello, World!]

Thanks to [DigitalTrauma](/users/11259/digitaltrauma) and [sch](/users/8330/sch) for the help :-D

Comment: Great!! :-) I wanted to write something like that. Unbeatable! All the [esoteric languages](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/286/2800) will finally get their ass kicked today! :-)

Comment: You can shave off one char by using single-quotes: `convert 'label:Hello world!' a.png`

Comment: `convert label:Hello\ world! a.png` is even shorter.

Comment: @sch - True - I was thinking the `!` needed escaping when unquoted, but it only needs escaping when in double quotes.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, it doesn't necessarily means escaping when in double quotes. It's just that here it was `!"` (which is looking for an event starting with `"` in the history).

Comment: Also, if you make it `sh`, you don't have to worry about `!` and you make it even less esoteric.

Comment: Would it be valid to save the image with the filename 'a'?

Comment: @Vortico: I think `convert` looks at the extension to figure out what format to save in. Otherwise you would have to specify PNG explicitly, which is longer than the extension.

Comment: Save one character if you change ".png" to ".ps" to save to postscript

Comment: @alexy13 The task is to create a png.

Comment: Frankly I don't think bash qualifies as a programming language here or that convert qualifies as an API. But in this case I'd throw `GNU hello` in and bring this contraption down to 29 with: `convert label:"\`hello\`" h.png`

Comment: Why do you even care for the extension of the file? Just call it `a` and the mime type will do the rest.

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret GNU hello is not very standard, e.g. it's not present on our debian server.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre 1) `convert` relies on the extension to choose the output format 2) Mime Type resolvers rely mostly on file extensions; in rare cases magic cookies

Answer (score 45):

## Mathematica <s>28</s> 27

This creates and exports the sentence, "Hello world!", as a PNG image.  1 char saved by Mechanical snail.

```
".png"~Export~"Hello world!"
```

---

**Testing**

This imports the PNG image.
The image was enlarged by dragging the image box handles.

[image: png]

Comment: 27 bytes: `".png"~Export~"Hello world!"`

Comment: Wow, two snails in a race! :-)

Answer (score 31):

## HTML, 1494

I know this won't win, but I didn't see this here before.

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Well apparently StackExchange will not allow data links so you must copy & paste it into your browser's address bar.

---

@squeamish ossifrage got it down to 176:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC0AAAAHAQAAAAC0VvlnAAAAOklEQVR4nGLIv/57/+9rDGDqAkPOterN0YIM3KG712pdZcgI3bW26gZD9lUwlRNWW1wtAAAAAP//AwCcyhjs3+7tWQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg
```

---

114

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACUAAAAEAQAAAAAhFcs9AAAAIElEQVQIHWOJit1f7szy58v9DAWWPaEMP7hZHHgi1aMB
```

---

@primo got it down to 112:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACYAAAAEAQAAAADKInA+AAAAH0lEQVR4nGOIj///7wVDZOBdoQ4G4dCrYWuA7JNiHQ
```

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19929/15891

Comment: You can easily compress this to 258 characters: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEIAAAANCAAAAAA4MeeNAAAAdklEQVR4Ac2QUQqFQAwDc9I5Ze6XB8HXXRFE8Mdg+zGEwa7yOurXdUb30ap+UIHkUSDRGg5K5D+SdRQ8iqbdTjmk043ihcQU9r8Y1aEY2A2Y1cte4KRIc1UYg58oIFYuhwQ5UgYp+yF+8Jz1Qgapsz/n23xE8QNxUbxuz+WqjAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==` http://pastebin.com/5TQzNv3D

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage got it down to 176: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC0AAAAHAQAAAAC0VvlnAAAAOklEQVR4nGLIv/57/+9rDGDqAkPOterN0YIM3KG712pdZcgI3bW26gZD9lUwlRNWW1wtAAAAAP//AwCcyhjs3+7tWQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg`. Must strip the hidden spaces.

Comment: 166 chars:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAD8AAAAFAQAAAADaxQm5AAAAM0lEQVQIW2Mo0a+w3iKQz8NQ+r56r+71/BIGlnwg40J+GUhkz9lr78sYShQ57O6IKfIAAJypEkNzAX3zAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC` http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19941/12800

Comment: 143 chars:
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACUAAAAEAQAAAAAhFcs9AAAAIElEQVQIHWOJit1f7szy58v9DAWWPaEMP7hZHHgi1aMBegAI03/J+AQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: 149 characters (retaining mixed case "Hello world!"): `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACYAAAAFAQAAAAABfqObAAAAJklEQVR4AWOIjv//7wWzBiNfnzzzc3klmY9MbgwMHCxMLGy6B3QAmcwIOOO9CusAAAAASUVORK5CYII`

Comment: I got it down to 135 characters! `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACUAAAAEAQAAAAAhFcs9AAAAIElEQVQIHWOJit1f7szy58v9DAWWPaEMP7hZHHgi1aMBegAI03/J+AQAAAAASUV=` (btw, that's 83bytes for a png image that says "Hello World", thought I might throw that out there!)

Comment: @timgws You can chop the last = off. It's only padding. In fact, you can chop off `egAI03/J+AQAAAAASUV=` to yield 114: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACUAAAAEAQAAAAAhFcs9AAAAIElEQVQIHWOJit1f7szy58v9DAWWPaEMP7hZHHgi1aMB

Comment: @Chloe the `IEND` is _required_ by the [PNG Specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2083#page-15): _"A valid PNG image must contain an IHDR chunk, one or more IDAT chunks, and an IEND chunk."_ It further states that any compliant decoder must treat any missing critical chunks as an error.

Comment: Valid png format - 140 bytes http://codepad.org/O0TwZbKF. No `IEND` - 124 bytes: http://codepad.org/QdutLeK1. No `IEND`, no `IDAT` crc32, no zlib adler32 - 112 bytes: http://codepad.org/R4srHxhh.

Comment: This isn't HTML. `<html><img src="data:...">` is HTML. This is just a URI.

Answer (score 28):

## C# - 168 chars

C# is better! ;)

```cs
using System.Drawing;class a{static void Main(){var s=new Bitmap(99,9);Graphics.FromImage(s).DrawString("Hello world!",new Font("",5),Brushes.Red,0,0);s.Save(".png");}}
```

Saves as .png in the current directory.

Rule abuse:

- Minimum font/image size has not been specified, so I settled for the minimum readable ;)
- Filename is empty (only extension!), but it works flawlessly.

To mirror the Java answer, here is the indented code:

```cs
using System.Drawing;
class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var s = new Bitmap(99, 9);
        Graphics.FromImage(s).DrawString("Hello world!", new Font("", 5), Brushes.Red, 0, 0);
        s.Save(".png");
    }
}
```

.net's API is a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of making the file call just `.png`. :)

Comment: I don't see how this is much cleaner than the Java one.

Comment: It is much cleaner than the Java one.

Comment: @immibis I can point the following: Character count is 28% lower, because of: no checked exceptions(`throws Exception`); the `var` keyword; `Save` is a method of the image itself, in contrast to `javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(b...`; file type is automagically inferred from the extension, no need to specify a separate `"png"`; No need to instantiate a `File` object as in `new java.io.File("p")`; `Main` method doesn't need to receive a parameter. The general idea is the same: create an image, use `Graphics` to write to it, and save it - but here it is done with more clear and succint method calls.

Comment: But C# doesn't have wildcards in generics. And anonymous classes. And return type covariance. And some other things I'm too lazy to recall.

Comment: @Sarge Yes we do, reflection for when we need them. Yes we do. What do you mean? Covariance works in C#.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

Comment: @Sarge I could see how that could sometimes be useful but we'd use generics in C# for this instead. Sometimes we really do want it to just return that type.

Comment: can the use of f# reduce char count?

Comment: @Rozuur I guess it should, but I'm no expert in F# so I didn't use it.

Answer (score 25):

### Linux shell + various utilities: 48 bytes

My first thought was to print `Hello World!` in the console, and then take a screenshot (after a small delay to avoid the race condition) using `scrot`:

```
echo Hello World\!;scrot -d1
```

(28 bytes). Unfortunately, this fails the "and nothing else" requirement: it will generally show other things like window decorations.

So instead, do it inside a full-screen `xterm`. This covers up any other windows and hides window decorations. It also satisfies the background-color requirement, since `xterm` defaults to a white background.

Because `xterm` displays a black cursor, we also need to tell it to hide the cursor. That can be accomplished using a terminal escape sequence: ESC `[` `?` `2` `5` `l`.

The option to make it full-screen is `-fullscreen`. However, it seems to work if you abbreviate the option to the shortest unambiguous possibility, `-fu`, saving 8 bytes.

The final code (48 bytes) is:

```
xterm -fu -e 'echo \x1b[?25lHello World!;scrot -d1'
```

(where `\x1b` denotes a literal ESC character, which takes 1 byte). By default, `scrot` writes the screenshot to a timestamped PNG file in the current directory.

It works on my system:

[image: output]

Comment: You missed some `scrot` options - I often use `-s` (interactively select window), but in this case you can use `-u` to grab the current (focused) window only.

Answer (score 19):

### Processing, <strike>38</strike> 37

This might be considered cheating, but:

```
text("HeΠo World!",9,8);save(".png");
```

[image]

---

38 char solution:

```
text("Hello World!",9,9);save(".png");
```

Saves this image as `.png`:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

## Java - <s>340</s> <s>339</s> <s>292</s> <s>261</s> <s>239</s> <s>236</s> 233 chars

This outputs a file just called `p` with a transparent background and white text:

```java
import java.awt.image.*;class R{public static void main(String[]y)throws Exception{BufferedImage b=new BufferedImage(80,9,2);b.getGraphics().drawString("Hello World!",5,9);javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(b,"png",new java.io.File("p"));}}
```

Here a properly-indented version. Should be pretty clear what is going on:

```java
import java.awt.image.*;

class R {
    public static void main(String[] y) throws Exception {
        // 2 = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(80, 9, 2);
        b.getGraphics().drawString("Hello world!", 5, 9);
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(b, "png", new java.io.File("p"));
    }
}
```

You might argue that white text in a transparent background is awful for reading and the file being called just `p` without the `.png` extension is awful too. So this longer variant version with 290 chars use red text and outputs a file called `p.png`:

```java
import java.awt.image.*;import java.awt.*;class R{public static void main(String[]y)throws Exception{BufferedImage b=new BufferedImage(80,9,2);Graphics g=b.getGraphics();g.setColor(Color.RED);g.drawString("Hello world!",5,9);javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(b,"png",new java.io.File("p.png"));}}
```

That properly-indented:

```java
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;

class R {
    public static void main(String[] y) throws Exception {
        // 2 = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(80, 9, 2);
        Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 5, 9);
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(b, "png", new java.io.File("p.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use BufferedImage, or does Image work?

Comment: @Quincunx I need `BufferedImage`. The `write` method parameter is of type `RenderedImage`, so it won't compile with just `Image` without some cast.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: technically you can call the file "p" and still match the requirements, since the saved file will be a png even if the filename doesn't reflect that.

Comment: @TimB Ok, did that.

Comment: @Victor, am I correct in thinking that `throws Exception` throws an exception if something goes wrong in `public static void main()`? Can you add `throws Exception` to other methods/extension methods in Java? I haven't seen this in C# before.

Comment: @user-12506 Yes, you can add `throws Exception` to other methods, but the compiler enforce this rule: if you call a method that might throw a `Throwable` that is not a `RuntimeException` or an `Error`, then the compiler will require that you either catch or rethrow it, and this includes `Exception`. Further, although it is allowed, declaring `throws Exception` is a bad programming practice, because `Exception` is way too generic to be effectively handled in practice and rethrowing it just spread the bad practice to elsewhere.

Comment: @Victor thanks for explaining. I thought it looked like a cool way of handling exceptions. Good to know :)

Comment: @user-12506 It's called *checked exceptions*. Look it up. :)

Comment: @ntoskrnl it's unlikely I'll look into it too much. I've never been a big fan of Java's syntax. IAmMoreOfACSharpKindaGuy - notAnEverythingSeemsToBeginWithALowerCaseCharacterKindaGuy(noOffenseIntended) - :)

Comment: I've skinned over a few pages about `checked exceptions` and just from reading the first paragraph or two, everybody seems to talk about it in a negative undertone. A little disappointing. I will look into this more when I wake up.

Comment: @user-12506 Not everything is lower case in Java – classes are CamelCase just like in C#. Methods and fields are lowerCamelCase, and packages are alllowercase. Makes it somewhat easier to determine what a name refers to, in my opinion.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Yeah, things can and do get a bit confusing when classes, methods and other things are camel case. But in the case of methods, it either begins with an Identifier that allows you to immediately recognize it as such, and if you're calling a method, you'll know right away that it's a method because it ends in (); or (somethinginHere);. In C#, most things are CamelCase (when I'm typing anyway), except for variables. and (most) `types`. Either way, I'm going to have to get used to Java eventually. I've just started my first serious Android project.

Comment: Save 1 char - `Heỻo world!`

Comment: @Timtech, at least for me ỻ was rendered as a square in the resulting image. Here in the browser (using firefox), it renders as a box containing 1EFB. I strongly suspect that this is not portable.

Answer (score 14):

## Fortran 90, <strike>104</strike> 94 bytes:

Aight, game on. Fortran 90, using the g2 graphics library and implict typing, so "d" is a real:

```
d=g2_open_gd('h',80.,12.,g2_gd_png)
call g2_string(d,1,1,'Hello world!')
call g2_close(d)
end
```

Needs to have the g2 library installed, then just compile with

```
gfortran -lg2 -fsecond-underscore p.f90
```

Thanks [Kyle Kanos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11376/kyle-kanos) for suggesting to drop "program p"!

I'm pretty satisfied that I beat C#, C + Cairo, Java, Javascript, Python and Ruby! And now also Perl!

Example output:
[image: example PNG produced by Fortran]

Comment: This can be shortened to 93 characters by eliminating `program p` as it is not necessary (the only necessary part of a F90 code is `end`).

Answer (score 11):

## R, <strike>52</strike> 39 chars

```
png()
frame()
text(.5,1,"Hello World!")
```

Saves as Rplot001.png in current directory. To be run as a script in non-interactive (batch) mode.

Thanks to Sven Hohenstein and Michael Hoffman for updates!

Comment: I count 52 characters...

Comment: @SvenHohenstein sorry you are correct. I made a mistake while attempting shorter versions (they didn't work).

Comment: `dev.off()` is unnecessary when you run this as a script instead of interactively.

Answer (score 10):

### PHP + gd2 - 86 bytes

```
<?imagestring($i=imagecreatetruecolor(97,16),4,2,0,'Hello world!',65535);imagepng($i);
```

`imagecreatetruecolor` is used instead of the shorter `imagecreate`, because colors can used directly without having to allocate them with `imagecolorallocate`. `65535` corresponds to hex color `#00FFFF`, a.k.a. cyan. I could have used `255` for blue, but it's fairly hard to see on a black canvas.

[image]

If the requirement that the background must be white or transparent is to be strictly enforced, I think the best that can be done is **98 bytes**:

```
<?imagestring($i=imagecreatetruecolor(97,16),4,2,0,'Hello world!',imagefilter($i,0));imagepng($i);
```

The `0` sent to `imagefilter` is the value of the constant `IMG_FILTER_NEGATE`, which of course negates the image. The result, `1`, is then used as the paint color (`#000001`):

[image]

Another option at **108 bytes**:

```
<?imagestring($i=imagecreatetruecolor(97,16),4,2,imagecolortransparent($i,0),'Hello world!',1);imagepng($i);
```

Setting black to be transparent, and drawing with `#000001` instead.

[image]

---

### PHP + *No Library* - 790+ bytes

```
<?
echo pack('CA3N2',137,'PNG',218765834,13);
echo $ihdr = pack('A4N2C5','IHDR',45,7,1,0,0,0,0);
echo hash('crc32b',$ihdr,true);
$data =
  '--------0  0      0 0                        0    0 0---'.
  '--------0  0      0 0                        0    0 0---'.
  '--------0  0  00  0 0  00    0   0  00  0 0  0  000 0---'.
  '--------0000 0  0 0 0 0  0   0   0 0  0 00 0 0 0  0 0---'.
  '--------0  0 0000 0 0 0  0   0 0 0 0  0 0    0 0  0 0---'.
  '--------0  0 0    0 0 0  0   0 0 0 0  0 0    0 0  0  ---'.
  '--------0  0  000 0 0  00     0 0   00  0    0  000 0---';
$bytes = join(array_map(chr,array_map(bindec,str_split(strtr($data,' -',10),8))));
$cmp = gzcompress($bytes);
echo pack('N',strlen($cmp));
echo $idat = 'IDAT'.$cmp;
echo hash('crc32b',$idat,true);
echo pack('NA4N',0,'IEND',2923585666);
```

Ahh, that's better. No bloat; exactly as much as required, and not a chunk more.
The result is this **109 byte** png:

[image]

Or, URI encoded (which seems to be trending...) at **168 bytes**:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC0AAAAHAQAAAAC0VvlnAAAANElEQVR4nGPIv/7//+8LDFAq51r15mgBBu7Q3Wu1LjBkhO5aW3WBIfsqkLrBkBNWW1wtAACw2RlgLInRogAAAABJRU5ErkJggg`

Supposing we wanted to cut that down a bit more, let's say we replace the data string with this:

```
$data =
  '--------0  0      0 0                    0   0 0'.
  '--------0  0  00  0 0 000   0   0 000 00 0 000 0'.
  '--------0000 0 00 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0'.
  '--------0  0 00   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0  '.
  '--------0  0  000 0 0 000   00 00 000 0  0 000 0';
```

(and update the header to the new dimensions, 40x5), the output would be this **96 byte** png:

[image]

Which URI encodes to **150 bytes**:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAFAQAAAAAft5MoAAAAJ0lEQVR4nGPIv/7//y6GnCvlLosYuEJLQ1cxZF4tDV3NkBNS5LoIANqBDTt5Av0NAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC`

I think that's about as small as you're going to be able to get, and still be considered "human readable".

#### Further Analysis

You may have noticed that we've been toting along an extra byte at the beginning of each scanline (denoted by `--------`). This isn't solely for decoration. Each byte specifies the [filtering](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#9Filters) used by each scanline. According to the PNG specification, *"Filtering transforms the PNG image with the goal of improving compression."* So let's try that.

The are five different filtering operations which can be applied independently to each scanline. The PHP implementation that I used for each can be seen here: http://codepad.org/xCQpBPC3 where `$bytes` represents the raw bytes for the current scanline, and `$prior` represents the raw, unfiltered bytes for the scanline above the current.

Let's start with the first 45x7 image. Seven scanlines each with 5 different filterings makes 78125 different possibilities to grind through. The initial encoding of the data block was 52 bytes in length, and after a bit of grinding zlib found a one byte improvement using filtering pattern [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] (that is, the first four scanlines with Sub filtering, and the last three unfiltered). The result is this **108 byte** png:

[image]

Which of course looks identical to the last. But I'm not convinced that zlib is producing the best possible encoding, and I think i have [good reason](http://garethrees.org/2007/11/14/pngcrush/) to be skeptical. I decided to try [AdvanceComp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdvanceCOMP) (which uses the same DEFLATE engine used for 7-zip), and [Zopfli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zopfli), an implementation which claims to *"find a low bit cost path through the graph of all possible deflate representations."* Sure enough, Zopfli mananged to compress the same data data pattern [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] down to 50 bytes, producing this **107 byte** png:

[image]

Once again, visually identical. (As a point of interest, it should probably be mentioned at this point that AdvanceComp with the setting `-z3` (compress-extra (7z)) didn't manage to find anything shorter than 60 bytes - the data was left uncompressed. It seems it refuses to compress anything this short). The above URI encodes to **165 bytes**:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC0AAAAHAQAAAAC0VvlnAAAAMklEQVR4AWPMz9Bg+HMVRuVkLbVYsZWR2yvtU+0yhozQXWurLjBkXwVSNxhywmqLqwUA+IMVKa7QjrYAAAAASUVORK5CYII`

Fully 11 bytes shorter than [squeamish ossifrage's attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19801/#comment40035_19907) at more or less an identical image.

Onwards to the 40x5 image. Five lines with 5 filterings each means we only have 3125 possibilities this time. The original encoding was 39 bytes in length, and with a bit of grinding, zlib found quite a few 38s. The one I've chosen is [1, 0, 0, 2, 0], which contains the largest number of unfiltered lines, and Sub and Up filters on lines 0 and 4, which are the simplest. Zopfli wasn't able to improve this result any further. The result is this **95 byte** png:

[image]

Which URI encodes to **149 bytes**:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAFAQAAAAAft5MoAAAAJklEQVR4nGPMz9Bg2M2Qc6XcZREDV2hp6Cqm+AYGBkaGnJAi10UAju4JJ/1zkEIAAAAASUVORK5CYII`

You might be tempted to think that the last 18 or so bytes of this aren't necessary. After all, this **121 byte** URI will still display correctly, at least in Chromium:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAFAQAAAAAft5MoAAAAIUlEQVR4nGPMz9Bg2M2Qc6XcZREDV2hp6Cqm+AYGBkaGnJAi10U`

But if you save it to a file, it will break in very many image viewers. In fact, any compliant decoder is required to report an error. So what have we chopped off?

From end towards beginning:

- 4 bytes - CRC32 for `IEND` chunk (always `0xAE426082`)
- 4 bytes - `IEND` chunk marker (always `IEND`)
- 4 bytes - `IEND` chunk length (always `0x00000000`)
- 4 bytes - CRC32 for `IDAT` chunk
- 4 bytes - Adler32 for zlib data
- 1 byte - Stop marker for zlib data

Additionally adjusting the `IDAT` length marker down by 5 (to compensate for the bytes we deleted) seems to "fix" the image in Windows Previewer.

Comment: The question state that it should have a white or transparent background. I myself think that the rules should be relaxed to allow black too, but for now, it fails the spec at this point.

Comment: @Victor Unfortunately, the gd2 library - as exposed by PHP, at least - doesn't have an option to specify the default color. Setting black to be transparent does work, though. Or simply to negate the entire image before adding the text.

Answer (score 9):

## Octave, 47

```
axis('off')
title("Hello World!")    
print -dpng x.png
```

[image]

Comment: -1 until you remove the axes (I think it would be `axis('off')`, not sure, see [here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/axis.html)) It would also be nice if you attached the generated output as well.

Comment: +1 now `:D`  why bother keeping the bigger/broken ones though...

Answer (score 9):

## C + Cairo: <s>238</s> <s>221</s> 202 bytes

```
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
main(){cairo_surface_t*s=cairo_image_surface_create(0,99,50);cairo_t*c=cairo_create(s);cairo_move_to(c,0,9);cairo_show_text(c,"Hello world!");cairo_surface_write_to_png(s,"o");}
```

$ cc `pkg-config cairo --libs --cflags` mini.c && ./a.out && display o

Here is the un-minified version:

```
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
void main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_surface_t *surf;
    surf = cairo_image_surface_create (0, 99, 50);
    cr = cairo_create (surf);
    cairo_move_to (cr, 0, 9);
    cairo_show_text (cr, "Hello world!");
    cairo_surface_write_to_png (surf, "out.png");
}
```

Best enjoyed while listening to [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S1fISh-pag) :)

Comment: You can save some chars by removing the type declaraction, i.e. the `void` for `main` and the `int` for `x`, and possibly the `char` for `**a` (I'm not sure about the last one though). In C the type is default to be `int` if no type is specified, and you don't necessarily need to return a value for `int main`. This may produce compilation warning messages, but not errors and the program will still work.

Comment: Shaved 17 bytes by removing the pointless `#define C(n,...) …`. Also, `main` returns `int`, not `void` (and as of C99 it's not required to explicitly "`return 0`" at the end of `main`; the implementation implicitly adds it for you).

Comment: @ace Thank you! I had forgotten that types defaults to int i C. But it looks like it's all-or-nothing; you can't have some variables in the call signature use default types while others don't. So I just changed it to `main()` and hardcode the filename to `o` instead of passing it to main. Now it's smaller than the Java version :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone Thanks! Did not know that C99 add an implicit `return 0` to main if not already there. That was why I choose to (incorrectly) return `void` instead of `int`. Since you got rid of the vararg macro, C99 is not required to compile the code anymore. <rant>Which makes it more portable to compilers who's vendors has chosen to not implement C99 [read: Microsoft] :)</rant>

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript! <s>105</s> <s>104</s> 101

```
c=document.createElement('canvas');open(c.toDataURL(c.getContext('2d').fillText('Hello world!',0,9)))
```

Outputs this size-optimized and pretty image:

[image: Hello world!]

Answer (score 9):

> make a PNG image that ***says*** "Hello world!" …

You'll hopefully excuse my very loose interpretation of the above requirement. :)

#### OSX bash:

```
printf '"Hello world!" and nothing else on a distinguishable background using only an image making API (eg ImageMagick) and return the image.' > hello.png
say -f hello.png
```

Comment: But it's not a PNG image, is it?

Comment: Well, it's technically a .png file, and it does *say* what is needed. :-)

Comment: PNG image is not "ASCII text, with no line terminators", as said by `file`. It's a .png file, but not PNG image.

Comment: Fail point. I didn't manage to find a way to fool the `file` utility by pre-pending the whole thing with the relevant code (i.e. decimals `137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10`). Perhaps you might know of a way? ;-)

Comment: seems you'd need to make full header with all information like dimensions, palette etc., because `file` prints this information. With your relevant code it only says "data".

Answer (score 8):

### TI-BASIC, 22

```
Text(0,0,"HELLO WORLD!
```

White background. Use TI-Connect if you wish to retrieve it from the calculator. Resulting PNG:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? Produces a .PNG image with the text `HELLO WORLD!`

Comment: While I don't know for definite, I'm going to assume that Ti-Connect generates and outputs the PNG here.

Comment: @slackwear That's for transfer, it's already on the calculator.

Comment: There's a PNG file on the calculator?

Comment: @slackwear Yes, used by the graph. System variables are `Pic1` through `Pic9`. PNG file is 94 by 62.

Comment: The calculator may have a 94 by 62 bitmap, stored in its own uncompressed format. I'll put my money on Ti-Connect converting it into a PNG when it's retrieved.

Comment: Can you post the resulting PNG?

Comment: This does not produce a .png image in the calculators memory. Retrieving it from the calculator converts it to a .png image.

Comment: Personally, I think this is like displaying `Hello world!` on my computer screen and then saying "Oh, but I can easily convert it to a .png by taking a screenshot of it!"

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby, 138

I'm golfing this hole with just my putter.  (I chose a PNG library without fonts or a string draw method.)

```
require'chunky_png';i=ChunkyPNG::Image.new 34,4
136.times{|v|i[*(v.divmod(4))]=9*(0xb0fae0f02e0eae0ece00eae0f0f0bf0f2f&1<<v)>>v};i.save ?h
```

Actual output is 34x4 pixels.  (Enlarged below.)  This plots very, *very* small and *nearly* transparent hand-drawn chars onto a very small transparent background. Image is saved to a PNG file named `h`.

[image: output]

Comment: Would it be shorter in Ruby to store `0xb0...` in Base64 and call a decode function?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail, I *think* that would require another `require` and then some, so the savings would be blown. I think.  I did look at Base 36 (since that can be done with `to_i` alone) but that ends up a bit longer.

Answer (score 8):

## BASH + RST + ImageMagick = 43 chars

Just for fun, here's another (quite ugly) one:

```
echo 'Hello World!'|rst2pdf|convert - a.png
```

Output:

[image: Hello World!]

Answer (score 6):

**Gnuplot**

Not really a true competitor, just for fun.
([homepage](http://www.gnuplot.info/))

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal pngcairo
set output "hw.png"
set label "Hello\nWorld!"
unset xtics
unset ytics
set yrange [-1:+1]
plot -1 notitle
```

or, as a oneliner (thanks to Phil H): 74 characters

```
se te pngc;se ou "q.png";se la "Hello world!";se yr[-1:1];uns ti;pl -1 not
```

Comment: You can shorten each of those commands to the minimum unique stub - so `set te` works, and `set out` etc. And you only need the top line to make it executable in the terminal, which is not a usual code golf requirement. So: `se te pngc;se ou "q.png";se la "Hello world!";se yr[-1:1];uns ti;pl -1 not` - 74 chars

Comment: @Phil H: yeah, sure, thanks ;-) Actually I knew commands could be shortened, but as this contrib wasn't really designed to compete with more efficient solutions, I thought I might as well show full length commands for educational purposes.

Answer (score 5):

### **Perl, 95:**

The whole command incantation:

```
perl -MGD::Simple -e'$i=new GD::Simple;moveTo$i 9,50;string$i "Hello world!";print$i->png'>.png
```

Because of (reasonable) module defaults, it's **95** characters (or **92** if single letter file name allowed).

On Windows we need to `binmode STDOUT`, the shortest way I think can be `-M-encoding`+ get rid of double colons:

```
perl -MGD'Simple -M-encoding -e"$i=new GD'Simple;moveTo$i 9,50;string$i 'Hello world!';print$i->png">.png
```

i.e. **105**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Data URI: 446

Following Chloe's idea, applied some basic optimisation to the image.

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEEAAAALCAAAAAAFX7+TAAABBUlEQVQoz2P4Tylg+M8IohiRRUCIkC6E0sFlwhFBJo5kmPAdWSYmuTsgGa6y/3pMf/8yLYEJMcQwARXckmZi8YCawAAG//8L537ZxbEMaoKCwuvXCkogE2y0/nMyL1vC/BcmxKC6AqhAXurBc1kGkNUINzCBDIqFmsB84f//c8wgmcVs91j13d3U4EIMl0AKmM78/38GqJQXyQSWQ///H3sJMwGo7ALYhL/MQUq1wkK1cCEGsE+ZgSacAzKNkUxQ1/kygfEczBeKb18rKICDS4U58SUT8ye4EMQEBelHz+WAzEokE+6IM7HkI4ekLDgk/5cxnPrPK/4fLgQxARSSUdCQpBQAAFZKE8rQG60FAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

Might be able to hack it further, but then would not be a perfectly conformant PNG and some viewers may not display it correctly.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of optimizations did you perform?

Comment: PNG2, stripped optional chunks, optimal (not streamed) compression

Comment: If you reduce the font size slightly, remove the spacing, the actual binary size of the image would be smaller than some of the posted solutions.

Comment: @OrangeDog I got it down to 179: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC0AAAAHAQAAAAC0VvlnAAAAOklEQVR4nGLIv/57/+9rDGDqAkPOterN
0YIM3KG712pdZcgI3bW26gZD9lUwlRNWW1wtAAAAAP//AwCcyhjs3+7tWQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That doesn't load in Firefox for me.

Comment: @OrangeDog Oops, should be 178. Try without the line break.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @OrangeDog: Stack Exchange comments seem to insert U+200B and U+200C into the comment. It works in Firefox once I strip them out.

Comment: Actually, the pad `=` characters are optional in Base64, giving 177 chars.

Comment: Can you add a working one to the answer?

Answer (score 5):

### Python and Matplotlib - <strike>66</strike> 65 chars

```
from pylab import*;title('Hello world!');axis('off');savefig('X')
```

Bit of whitespace, but it has the text and nothing else.  File is saved as `X.png`:

[image]

Comment: `from pylab import*`

Comment: @Timtech thanks, I'm a golfing noob clearly ;)

Comment: I think you did a great job!

Answer (score 4):

## Python with PIL 122 Chars

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw;d=Image.new("RGB",(70,9));i=ImageDraw.Draw(d);i.text((0,0),"Hello World!");d.save("a.png")
```

It could probably be much smaller but I haven't worked with PIL extensively and made this in 5 minutes.

Output:
[image]

Comment: You beat me to it by 10 minutes! With about 10 less chars! +1 :D Lose another char by going from 10 to 9 in your ``new``, but you left out the ``!``.

Comment: The question state that it should have a white or transparent background. I myself think that the rules should be relaxed to allow black too, but for now, it fails the spec at this point.

Comment: Couldn't you save lots of characters with `from PIL import*`?

Comment: You would expect so, but you have to import them individually or else you get a not defined error `from PIL import Image,ImageDraw;d=Image.new("RGB",(66,10));i=ImageDraw.Draw(d);i.text((0,0),"Hello World");d.save("a.png")` `NameError: name 'Image' is not defined`

Answer (score 4):

### Ghostscript command line incantation, 84 (i.e. Postscript) :

```
 gs -sDEVICE=png16 -oa.png -c '/ 72 selectfont 9 9 moveto(Hello world!)show showpage'
```

Missing font message is intentional ;-). And proper (i.e. not hidden) name for our PNG file, too :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, with <s>118</s> <s>115</s> <s>117</s> <s>116</s> 114 chars

Here's a full criteria passing with white text on alpha background at <s>116</s> 114 chars!:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw as D
m=Image.new("LA",(99,9))
D.Draw(m).text((9,0),'Hello World!')
m.save('r.png')
```

(You can replace newlines with semicolons - count is the same regardless.)

Comment: `ImageDraw as D`, and then `D.Draw` saves 3 chars.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + DOT, <s>46</s> 41

```
dot -Tpng<<<'graph{label="Hello World!"}'
```

This outputs a png into the standard output. It is saving a file, but I don't think that was a requirement.

Outout: [image: Hello World!]

Comment: I we allow them be in ellipses, it can be 8 chars shorter...

Comment: I am not sure whether you should add the bash chars as well for compiling this dot script. This adds `dot -Tpng -op d`, which is 15 chars.

Comment: You should count the command line options/argument if they are needed to make your program solve the task. Normally the dashes are not counted, so I think you only should add `Tnpg`, `op` and `d` to the character count (+7), and specify how to run it in the answer itself.

Comment: It can be better if you don't `echo` but instead write it in a file and run `dot -Tpng` on the file; it makes it 38, but I don't know if it counts...

Comment: Why would it not count?

Comment: Hans, I decided for fair play :) **Golf it down to 41** with the improvement I suggested in my answer: `dot -Tpng<<<'graph{label="Hello World!"}'`, I will delete my answer then. These derivations shouldn't be done in fair play and should stay as a comments to original answers.

Comment: Updated according to Tomas' suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## PureBasic - 128 chars

```
UsePNGImageEncoder()
CreateImage(0,99,24)
StartDrawing(ImageOutput(0))
DrawText(0,0,"Hello World!")
SaveImage(0,"a.png",4673104)
```

[image]

Not the shortest here, but I have to support my favorite Basic language :)

edit: just in case there is a complain about the black background, at 133 chars:

```
UsePNGImageEncoder()
CreateImage(0,80,16)
StartDrawing(ImageOutput(0))
DrawText(0,0,"Hello World!",0,-1)
SaveImage(0,"a.png",4673104)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol/View 45

```
save/png %i to-image layout[h1"Hello World!"]
```

writes a png image file named i into current directory
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### bash + netpbm: 31 chars

```
pbmtext "Hello world!"|pnmtopng
```

Will make:

[image: Hello world by netPBM]

Answer (score 2):

## Internet 11

Internet is an API!

[ow.ly/thgUJ](http://ow.ly/thgUJ) -> http://dummyimage.com/99x9/f/0.png&text=Hello+world!

Comment: Clever! Google charts is more readable ;) http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=Hello%5C+world%21

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab: 47 characters

I'm not sure what exactly an Image making API is.  This uses a figure/graph making API, which is arguably an image.

```
text(1,1,'Hello World!');axis off;print -dpng f
```

[image: Matlab example]

Answer (score 1):

### EPL, 28

```
0,0,0,1,1,1,N,"Hello World!"
```

Comment: Can you show the output?

Answer (score 1):

Chloe used a Base64 encoded approach with 1494 characters, however you can easily reduce the size:

## Anchor link - 166 chars

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAD8AAAAFAQAAAADaxQm5AAAAM0lEQVQIW2Mo0a+w3iKQz8NQ+r56r+71/BIGlnwg40J+GUhkz9lr78sYShQ57O6IKfIAAJypEkNzAX3zAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

Paste this into your browser

Comment: 157, see: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19828

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, using Google's chart API: 92 characters

```
curl http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=|9|h|||Hello+world! > h.png
```

[image]

### Further optimization: 33 characters

```
curl http://goo.gl/a8ntA4 > h.png
```

[image]

Comment: Don't know if the "further optimization" counts, as it caches data in the cloud in the form of a shortened URL service, which allows one to make a script of arbitrary size and complexity to solve this problem that never requires more than 33 characters to represent.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't think using a URL shortener is very kosher for this. :-)

Comment: I have a shorter solution: `cat image.png > h.png` where image.png is the result of `curl http://goo.gl/a8ntA4 > image.png`!!!

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 41 chars

@gerrit posted a MATLAB solution as well, but since I don't have enough rep to comment, I'll post mine too. (The output is the same as his, so I don't want to take up more space with the resulting PNG).

```
axis off,title 'Hello world!',print -dpng
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 133

Not going to win any points for size here as it's just an abbreviated Java.

No color setting:

```
i=new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(75,30,2);i.graphics.drawString('Hello World',5,20);javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(i,'PNG',System.out)
```

With setting color (164):

```
i=new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(75,30,2);g=i.graphics;g.color=java.awt.Color.RED;g.drawString('Hello World',5,20);javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(i,'PNG',System.out)
```

#### Formatted:

```
i = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(75,30,2)
g = i.graphics
g.color = java.awt.Color.RED
g.drawString('Hello World',5,20)
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(i,'PNG',System.out)
```

[image: hw.png]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cool trick, only 37 chars:
[placehold.it/png/99&text=Hello+world!](http://placehold.it/99/png&text=Hello+world!) (+7 chars for the protocol).

This generates a 239 bytes long png image with 99px of width and height.

I know it's not programming, but this is a website that generates placeholder images.

You should visit http://placehold.it.

Comment: similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20019

Comment: Similar, but WAAAAAAAAAAAAY shorter and a totally different website. dummyimage.com is bigger than placehold.it

Comment: http://cambelt.co/300/Hello+world! and http://fakeimg.pl/99/?text=Hello+world! are even shorter. Should I post two more answers with them? No. Multiple answers using the same language and principles are boring. If you have improvement for existing answer, please post it as comment.

Comment: If you didn't downvoted, perhaps I could get enough reputation to make comments on other posts!

Comment: Ah, that is indeed a good reason for not posting comment. Revoked the vote. (I had to make and edit to your post to be able to change my vote.)

Answer (score 0):

**Groovy, 151 (or 202 with a black text)**

a rewrite of the proposed Java version. Resulting image is with white text on a transparent background. Add 50 chars to have black text !

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage as B
B b=new B(80,9,2)
b.graphics.drawString("Hello world!",5,9)
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(b,"png",new File("p"))
```

The version with black text:

```
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage as B
B b=new B(80,9,2)
b.graphics.with {setColor(new Color(0)); drawString("Hello world!",5,9); }
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(b,"png",new File("p"))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the resulted image? By the way, are all those spaces necessary in the code?

Comment: image posted and useless spaces removed

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 192 chars:

I use [`RMagick`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/rvgtut.html) `RVG (Ruby Vector Graphics)`.

```
require 'rvg/rvg';include Magick;RVG::dpi = 72;RVG.new(1.5.in, 1.5.in){|canvas|canvas.background_fill = '#C0C0C0';canvas.text(10, 100){|title|;title.tspan("Hello World!")}}.draw.write('hw.png')
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Shell + Graphviz (55)

```
echo 'graph{a[label="Hello World!"]}'|dot -Tpng>h.png
```

Comment: @Timtech I don't know what shell you're using, but the ! works fine for me in bash and doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: That's really weird - all I did was add four spaces in front of your answer to format is correctly. I see what you mean, though O_o I don't remember doing that at all :S

Comment: alright, well I'm going to remove it then :)  Thanks for getting the code formatting, not sure how I missed it..

Comment: It's fine - I usually do that kind of stuff whenever I see it :)

Comment: You can get away with `echo 'graph{"Hello World!"}'|dot -Tpng>a.png`, which is 44 characters...

Comment: ...but you should really get rid of the ellipse, which you can do with `echo 'graph{"Hello World!"[shape=plaintext]}'|dot -Tpng>a.png`, which is 61 characters.

Answer (score -1):

## Mouse: 0 chars

"right click" > "save image as"

Result:

[image]

Comment: Where is the “with programming APIs” part here?