# Graphical Hello World

Tags: graphical-output, hello-world

In this challenge, you will create the shortest graphical program that displays exactly "**Hello, world!**"

You will need **no input**.

You might be asking yourself, "what does he mean by graphical?" Well, by graphical, I mean **not writing to stdout.** For example, look at my ES6 answer, which makes an alert box pop up rather than the traditional hello world where you do write to stdout:

```js
alert('Hello, world!')
```

That doesn't write to stdout. Which is what I am challenging you to do today.

#### Formatting

This is an example post in markdown for the ES6 snippet I posted above:

```
# JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

    alert('Hello, world!')
```

View an [example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247342/111787) post.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19801/87728). Also, is this code golf? It needs some scoring criteria. Can you elaborate more on what is allowed? (eg. is it acceptable to write to stderr?)

Answer (score 7):

## Minecraft Command Blocks, 47 bytes

```
summon cow ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'"Hello, world!"'}
```

Spawns a cow with the name `Hello, world!`[image: cow with name]

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

```
alert('Hello, world!')
```

This is an example for my question.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with `alert\`Hello, world!\``

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (8.1), 20 bytes

```
echo'Hello, world!';
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'm not sure if this counts, since with, e.g., `php -r` (if I'm remebering the flag right) it would go to STDOUT, but this question is probably going to be closed as unclear anyway.